# When does Roto Paint 2 decide to do "refine edge propagating"?

Tags: after-effects

If I am rotoscoping a long clip using RotoPaint 2 in After Effects, and I do the following:

Make a good rotopaint boundary in the middle of the clip, and adjust the Refine Edge tool around it to look right.

I then go to the beginning of the clip, and fix anywhere the rotopaint has messed up.  This requires the computer to process the frames back to the beginning.

Then I just to the end frame, allowing the computer to process the frames in between.

Then I move a few frames back towards the middle of the clip.

Why is the refine edge propagating backwards in time when I've already processed forward over that frame?